# Passing arguments in object in Python

Tags: python

I've got a main file and then a unit test file.  When I try to reference the main in the tester, it seems to run it once without letting me add any arguments.  The only line where I reference the main file right now is `import main` and don't mention main anywhere else in the code.  When I run the unit tester it runs main.py automatically.  Is there a different way I should be referencing it in?

Comment: `import module` runs the code in the module. Does main.py have an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard?

Comment: It does not.  Should I add one?

Comment: If you want to be able to `import` it without executing any code, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can give arguments to the unit tester and then reference your main program like this:

```
unittest.main(argv=[sys.argv[0]])
```